# XML to MS-Access 2007 using ASP.Net (Bulk Insert, Bulk Copy)

Tags: asp.net, xml, vb.net, sqlbulkcopy

I am download a XML file comprising thousands of records. I want that XML file to convert it to MS-Access 2007 Database using ASP.Net (VB) and run further queries on it. Its worth mentioning that the conversion should be done in bulk because its very heavy file and take longer to insert one by one record. I am tired of googling code to fulfill my requirements. I am also new to ASP.Net.
The XML file structure is as under:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
 <root>
  <PRODUCT ITEM="8101">
  <MODEL>FY316A</MODEL> 
  <EAN>5055071647109</EAN> 
  <NAME>Enchanted Twilight Flower Fairy 'Amethyst'</NAME> 
  <DESCRIPTION> some descriptio </DESCRIPTION>
  <DIMENSION>  <![CDATA[ Height 31 - 32cm Width 16 - 18.5cm Depth 12 - 13.5cm </DIMENSION>
  <PRICE>16.63</PRICE> 
  <DELIVERY>I</DELIVERY> 
  <OPTIONS>  <![CDATA[ B - Hand on Dress|A - Flower in Hand|Any  ]]>   </OPTIONS>
  </PRODUCT>
 </root>
```

Please write a complete piece of code for me to do this job.

Comment: Please don't expect other people to write code for you. Show some of the code you have written to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Access 2007 will directly import XML.  You can create an XSD for your particular data, then import that to create the table definitions. The XML should cleanly import from there.

Comment: Dear Karelzarath, Thank you for your reply. But I dont want it done manually, rather I want it be done automatically Using some script of ASP.Net(VB) as I have mentioned in my Question too. I need the script or any clue to that script.

Comment: Good luck and godspeed on your quest.